# .NET MVC: Restrict action based on Role level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

I wanted to know if there's a better way of doing this:
Let's suppose i have users with roles **"SuperUser"**, **Admin**, **"Manager"**, **"Registered"**.

All users registered in the site have the role "Registered" (for example "Manager" users also have the "Registered" role).

Now i've to manage the **Delete** action on Users controller. What I want to reach is:

- "Registered" users can delete only themselves (es: removing from site registration)
- "Manager" users can delete themselves and "Registered" users, bug **cannot** delete "SuperUser" and "Admin"
- "Admin" users can delete themselves, "Managers" and "Registered" users, bug **cannot** delete "SuperUser"
- "SuperUser" users can delete all user roles, even superusers.

So i started with the following code:

```
        [Authorize(Roles="Registered")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            string[] AllowedRoles = { "SuperAdmin", "Manager" };

            if (_identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData).Value == id.ToString())
            {
                //USER can delete himself!
                //TO DO: Deletion code
            }

            else if (User.IsInAnyRole(AllowedRoles))
            {
                //CHECK IF I CAN DELETE THE GIVEN USER
            }

        }
```

What I'm gonna do is check every role of current user with the user to delete, but I really don't like writing a lot of "if"....
There is a way to do it better?

Thanks!

PS: Don't worry about User.IsInAnyRole (it's a custom function that verify if the user is in one of the specified role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder, are there authenticated users that aren't "registered"? IMO this role is not necessary. If you don't agree you can adapt the code below.

I'm not sure what `_identity` and `User` is in your code, but I assume that `_identity` is the usermanager repository and `User` is the current httpcontext user. I assume you need the UserManager since you you won't be able to perform this test without access to the stored claims (as in *AspNetUserClaims*).

Please note that I didn't fully test this code.

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.Linq;
// using System.Security.Claims;

// This method is available for all authenticated users
[Authorize]
public void Delete(int id)
{
    // Test if current user wants to delete itself
    if (User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData).Value != id.ToString())
    {
        // Find all roles of the current user.
        var roles = User.FindAll("role").Select(r => r.Value).ToList();

        // A fixed list, ordered by importance
        var allowedRoles = new List<string> { "SuperAdmin", "Admin", "Manager" };
        // Highest role of the current user
        var role = allowedRoles.Intersect(roles).FirstOrDefault();

        // "Registered" user is not allowed to do anything with other users
        if (role == null)
            return;

        // Get the rolename(s) of the target user. Something like this, where
        // _identity is a repository (usermanager?) that has access to the database
        var targetUserRoles = _identity.Where(u => u.Id == id).Roles().Select(r => r.Name).ToList();
        //var targetUserRoles = new List<string> { "Admin" };

        // Highest role of the target user, because you don't want to delete
        // a user that is both Manager and SuperAdmin when you are Admin.
        var targetUserRole = allowedRoles.Intersect(targetUserRoles).FirstOrDefault();
        // Users without a matching role may be deleted
        if (targetUserRole != null)
        {
            // Determine the importance of the role of both
            // the current user and the target user
            var targetIndex = allowedRoles.IndexOf(targetUserRole);
            var index = allowedRoles.IndexOf(role);

            // Index==0 is SuperAdmin
            // Otherwise index of role of targetuser must be higher
            if (index > 0 && targetIndex <= index)
                return;
        }
    }

    // If we got here we can safely delete the user.

    //TO DO: Deletion code
}
```

If you want to extend the hierarchy you can simply add the claim value to the allowedRoles collection at the appropriate position.

Comment: Yes you assumed User and _identity right. :)
For some reasons I need a "registered" role and a "guest" role, but it doesn't matter. Your example is good! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A similar scenario to what I have done, instead of having roles as strings have then as enum flags

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions
{
    None = 0,
    Registered = 1 << 0,
    SuperAdmin = 1 << 1,
    Manager = 1 << 2,
    // Etc...
}
```

Using this you can then use this method on the user to determine which roles are allowed:

```
public bool IsInRole(Permissions roles)
{
    var rolesToCheck = roles.GetFlags().Where(p => p != Permissions.None);
    return rolesToCheck.Any(role => Roles.HasFlag(role));
}
```

and:

```
if(User.IsInRole(Permissions.SuperAdmin | Permissions.Manager)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Similarly you can also add this to the attribute by creating a custom extension of the Authorize attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public Permissions Roles { get; set; }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool authorized = false;
        var roleFlags = Roles.GetFlags();
        if (!roleFlags.All(r => r == Permissions.None))
        {
            foreach (var role in roleFlags.Where(p => p != RolePermissions.None))
            {
                if (maritimeUser.Roles.HasFlag(role))
                {
                    authorized = true;
                }
            }
        }

    if (Roles == Permissions.None)
    {
        // No roles set, so authorise = okay
        return;
    }

    if (!authorized)
    {
        filterContext.Result =
            new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"controller", "Account"},
                    {"action", "Unauthorised"},
                    {"area", "" }
                });
        return;
    }
}
```

and use by

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = Permissions.SuperAdmin | Permissions.Manager)]
```